# PHP Getting A Records Only Using dns_record

Tags: php, dns, ip, gethostbyname, dns-get-record

I am making an IP grab script for servers and I had some issues with my code. I want to grab just the ip addresses of servers using dns_get_record without the extra bloat in the default output. However, my current script displays a blank output when ran. And no. I can't simply use gethostbyname, as it has to be compatible with querying wan ips for the server the code is running on. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
function test() {
    $host = "google.com";
     $result = dns_get_record("$host", DNS_A);
foreach ($result as $record) {
    echo $record['target'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r($result);` ?

Comment: From where do you call test()? Just because that function is defined in a script, it still needs to be called. It does not automatically run based on definition alone. Before the closing PHP tag, add:  test();

Comment: That function is called later in a table. And I tried your suggestions, but it just displays this (I want the ip only): Array ( [host] => google.com [class] => IN [ttl] => 135 [type] => A [ip] => 172.217.4.142 ) Array ( [host] => google.com [class] => IN [ttl] => 135 [type] => A [ip] => 172.217.4.142 ) Array ( [host] => google.com [class] => IN [ttl] => 135 [type] => A [ip] => 172.217.4.142 )

Comment: Do you see IPv4 addresses somewhere?   ......... *Hint: try `$record['ip']`* ;)

Comment: Yes. That change worked! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed code (works properly):

```
function test() {
    $host = "google.com";
     $result = dns_get_record("$host", DNS_A);
foreach ($result as $record) {
    echo $record['ip'];
    }
}
```